# Newlines in Google App Script Embedded in Google Site?

Tags: google-apps-script, newline, saml

I'm a newb, so there's probably something obvious that I'm missing...

This code is embedded in a Google Site that my company uses.

Basically, what I've done is to create a text box where I past in a SAML Response, I click the button and it URL Decodes and then base64 decodes the string.  That works (surprisingly).  But the output is just a long line of the XML.  To get past this in python for example, I just replaced the "><" instances with ">\n<" and it formats it good enough for me.  (I don't need a true XML format)

I have tried too many things to list here, but either the things I've guessed at don't work, the formatting gets unreadable, it cuts off the text and doesn't word wrap, etc.  The current state does what I want, it just runs off the right side of the page (I can copy paste it, other things I've tried I can not do that) and doesn't put a newline in between the "><" when I add something there to try it.

Here is my ratty code, please ignore the comments, it's just stuff I've tried.:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('CAML Response Decoder');
  var testText = "Decoded Response Will Appear Here...";
  var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(2, 2);
  mygrid.setText(0, 0, 'SAML Response: ');
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, myapp.createTextBox().setName("SAMLin"));
  mygrid.setText(1, 0, 'Decoded: ');
//  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createTextBox().setName("SAMLout"));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createLabel(testText).setWordWrap(true).setId("SAMLout"));
//  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createHTML(testText).setId("SAMLout").setWordWrap(true).setWidth(50));
  var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Decode');
//  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel().setSize(800,500);
  var mypanel = myapp.createHorizontalPanel();
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  myapp.add(mypanel);

  var handler = myapp.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  mybutton.addClickHandler(handler);
  handler.addCallbackElement(mygrid);
  return myapp;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var textValue = e.parameter.SAMLin;
  var strURIDecoded = textValue.replace(/%2D/g, "-").replace(/%5F/g, "_").replace(/%2E/g, ".").replace(/%21/g, "!").replace(/%7E/g, "~").replace(/%2A/g, "*").replace(/%27/g, "'").replace(/%28/g, "(").replace(/%29/g, ")").replace(/%3Cbr%20%2F%3E/g, "%0D" ).replace(/%0A/g, "%0D" ).replace(/%250D/g, "%0D").replace(/%5Cr%5Cn/g, "%0D").replace(/%2B/g, "+").replace(/%5Cn/g, "%0D").replace(/%5Cr/g, "%0D").replace(/%3D/g, "=");
  var strB64Decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(strURIDecoded);
  var Assertion = Utilities.newBlob(strB64Decoded).getDataAsString();
  var AllDone = Assertion.replace(/></g, ">\n<");
//  var AllDone = ("<div>" + AllDone2 + "</div>");

//  var document = XmlService.parse(Assertion);
//  var AllDone = XmlService.getCompactFormat()
//     .setLineSeparator('\n')
//     .setEncoding('UTF-8')
//     .setIndent('   ')
//     .format(document);

  app.getElementById('SAMLout').setText(AllDone)  
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the label will allow anything that would create a new line.  You did try `.createHTML` which allows basic markup.  Try using HTML with a `<br>` tag.

[Line Break documentation - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

I haven't tried it, so I don't know if it works.

Other than that, I think you'd need to break up the content, and add a second label.

Comment: Hi.  I did try that.  It's one of the commented out lines.  It formats differently then and skews the output all over the place.  It somehow appears to misinterpret the XML (or maybe Google Site strips it out?) and only shows part of the text.  What do you mean about adding a second label?

Comment: You are creating a label with the ID "SAMLout", and then setting the text of that label, right?  And then putting the entire content into that label, and trying to get it to format with new lines.  What I'm saying is, create a new variable for every section of text you want on a new line, then create a label for every line you want, and set the text for that line.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I ended up using the .createHTML and then replacing all of the "<" and ">" with another character. It was all due to this being XML and Google Sites stripping out things that they don't like.  I'd love to hear other solutions though as this is quite a messy solution.